# Customizing the 'read more' link in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

Im trying to work on this site and I need to change the link in the "read more" button to another page (See picture, red circle).

How do I customize the destination of the "read more" link? This isn't an excerpt function, it is a clickable link that leads to a whole other page.

[image]

Comment: You can edit href area easyly.(a href="HERE") What is problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will add a link in a div after the excerpt.  Hide the initial read more link and that should work.  Although the read more link really was intended only to link to the full article.

```
function add_excerpt_link($more) {
global $post;
return '<a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '" class="custom-readmore-link">Custom Link</a>;';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'add_excerpt_link');
```

Comment: I kind of want to keep the 'read more' and just direct the viewer to another page. How do I edit it?

Comment: Post a link to your site.  You need to hide the original link that the above function replaces.

Comment: function add_excerpt_link($more) {
global $post;
return '<a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '" class="custom-readmore-link">Read More</a>;';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'add_excerpt_link');

Comment: <?php
     foreach ($query as $post) {
      setup_postdata($post);

      printf('<div>');
      printf('<div class="box">');
      printf('<h4>%s</h4>', $post->post_title);

      printf('<img src="%s" />', wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_id()), 'full')[0]);

      printf('<p>%s</p>', get_the_excerpt($post->ID));
      printf('<a href="%s" class="button">Read more</a>', post_permalink($post->ID));
      printf('</div>');
      printf('</div>');
     }

Comment: I was looking around and I found this. I think it is the code for all three read more buttons in the front page, so how do I change them so that their links lead to a page of my design?